# Java JDI ReferenceType get absolute path

Tags: java, jdi

Is it possible to get the absolute file path from a `ReferenceType` in JDI? I am wanting to list all line locations for a specific class, but the class is pulling in multiple reference types, so I want to be able to determine which one it is. These classes do not have namepsaces either to help with filtering.

IE `namespace user : location /user.java` for 2 cases.